# JaxWsPortProxyBean getting called multiple times?

Tags: java, xml, spring, soap, jax-ws

I am trying to convert existing SOAP services bean configuration from XML to JAVA . I get this weird issue where some bean configuration code are getting executed multiple times. It doesn't affect the functionality but it doesn't happen when I use xml configuration. The Java configuration I use inside `SpringConfig` class is this :

```
@Configuration
@ImportResource("classpath:webServices.xml")
public class mySpringConfig {

    public static int i = 0;

    @Inject
    ExceptionNormalizationAdvice exceptionNormalizationAdvice;

    @Inject
    private RequestHeaderInjectorAdvice requestHeaderInjectorAdvice;

    @Inject
    private CustomHandlerResolver customHandlerResolver;


     @Bean(name = "service1")
        public JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean service1() {
            i++;
            System.out.println("inside s1 " + i);
            JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean bean = new JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean();
            List<Advice> adviceList = new ArrayList<Advice>();
            adviceList.add(exceptionNormalizationAdvice);
            adviceList.add(requestHeaderInjectorAdvice);
            bean.setAdviceList(adviceList);
            bean.setHandlerResolver(customHandlerResolver);
            bean.setServiceInterface(service1Soap.class); //
            bean.setNamespaceUri("http://example.com/service1");
            bean.setWsdlDocumentUrl(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("service1.wsdl"));
            bean.setServiceName("service1");
            bean.setPortName("service1Soap");
            return bean;
        }

        @Bean(name = "service2")
        public JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean service2() {
            i++;
            System.out.println("inside s2 " + i);
            JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean bean = new JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean();
            List<Advice> adviceList = new ArrayList<Advice>();
            adviceList.add(exceptionNormalizationAdvice);
            adviceList.add(requestHeaderInjectorAdvice);
            bean.setHandlerResolver(customHandlerResolver);
            bean.setAdviceList(adviceList);
            bean.setServiceInterface(service2Soap.class); //
            bean.setNamespaceUri("http://example.com/servic2");
            bean.setWsdlDocumentUrl(this.getClass().getClassLoader()
                    .getResource("service2.wsdl"));
            bean.setServiceName("service2");
            bean.setPortName("service2Soap");
            return bean;

        }
}
```

When I tried printing out the text and count I got "inside s1" getting printed 2 times with count 4 and 8 and "inside s2" getting printed 6 times with counts ranging from 1 to 7 without 4 . The corresponding XML configuration for the service was this . Only service 1 is listed for sample and service 2 uses a similar configuration.

```
<bean id="service1"
        class="JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean">
        <property name="handlerResolver" ref="customHandleResolver" />
        <property name="serviceInterface" value="service1Soap" />
        <property name="wsdlDocumentUrl" value="classpath:META-INF/wsdls/service1.wsdl" />
        <property name="namespaceUri" value="http://example.com/service1" />
        <property name="serviceName" value="service1" />
        <property name="portName" value="service1Soap" />
        <property name="adviceList">
            <list>
                <ref bean="exceptionNormalizationAdvice"/>
                <ref bean="requestHeaderInjectorAdvice"/>
            </list>
  </property>
    </bean>
```

In the service classes I use the following method to inject the factory bean and use the proxy to communicate with the SOAP server .

```
@Resource(name="service1")
private service1Soap service1;

service1.callSomeMethod();
```

The `web.xml` contains this:

```
  <display-name>my-web</display-name>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
    <param-value>
          org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
      </param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>com.example.myown.core.CoreSpringConfig</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>spring.profiles.active</param-name>
    <param-value>my-content</param-value>
  </context-param>
    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
      <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>com.example.myown.web.WebMvcSpringConfig</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/myweb/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Both `WebMvcSpringConfig` and `CoreSpringConfig` has `@ComponentScan` annotation and scans the same basepackage  (`com.example.myown`) but `CoreSpringConfig` is excluded in `WebMvcSpringConfig` using `FilterType.Assignable_Type` .

The problem I face is when I count the number of times "inside s1" and "inside s2" it is more than once . I tried adding `excludeFilter` for `mySpringConfig` class inside `WebMvcSpringConfig` and now some of the redundant occurrence are gone but not all . Simply put the output for the `mySpringConfig` file(shown above) was:

```
inside s2 1
inside s2 2
inside s2 3
inside s1 4
```

If I move the `service1()` function below and `service2()` function to the top the output is also interchanged to this:

```
inside s1 1
inside s1 2
inside s1 3
inside s2 4
```

How come changing the position of the function inside a class changes the output? Ideally both should be printed only once . I tried searching for `@ComponentScan` in all places but it's used only in core spring config and `WebMVCSpringConfig` files and not anywhere else. I am sure the beans are initialized and configured properly since the above issue doesn't cause any problem to the functionality .

Note: The `webservices.xml` is imported for configuring other rest services and the soap services are commented out in the xml file .

Comment: Do you have a `ContextLoaderListener` and `DispatcherServlet`? Both with a `<context:component-scan />`...

Comment: @M.Deinum Yes that's right ! My contextLoaderListener and DispatcherServlet refer to different Java spring config classes and both theses classes has ComponentScan annotation in them . I thought the root application context would be loaded first and the child contexts tied up to them . Still couldn't understand how that will cause the issue which I have now since I use ExcludeFilter to prevent web context and app context from scanning same dependencies ?

Comment: Well they do refer to each other, however if a component-scan detects the same class it will create a new instance of it (regardless if it exists in the parent or not). So I guess something is loading the same `@Configuration` multiple times. (Remember a `@Configuration` is also `@Component`).

Comment: @M.Deinum Let's assume that's the case but still how come service1 is loaded only 2 times and service 2 is loaded 6 times and what's even more weird is that if I put service 2 in the top of the config file and move service 1 to the bottom the number of times they load is also interchanged .

Comment: Without more insight I cannot help you with answering that question, I'm also wondering if what you are seeing is what is actually happening. For the `@Configuration` classes there is a lot of proxying and bytecode enhancement going on. Which might interfere with the way you are logging things. Could you create a minimal sample which shows. your issue?

Comment: @M.Deinum I have added more context . I really appreciate your help !

Comment: The fact that you exclude your `CoreSpringConfig` doesn't mean you are excluding `mySpringConfig`. Also. your `CoreSpringConfig` should exclude the `WebSpringConfig` else that will be loaded twice as well. Also you are trying to do something with a static variable, which is shared in a class. So even if the class is instantiated again it will resume the counter. (I suspect that is what you are seeing).